# Calling methods in the JWinAPI

Tags: java

In Java, what is a call to an API? How to call a method of an API?

I like to call methods in the [JWinAPI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwinapi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question cannot be answered without more context. API means "Application Programming Interface". Any part of a program that is explicitly designed to be called from "outside" represents an API. There's APIs everywhere you look, which is why your question makes little sense.

Comment: Never heard that one before - normally it's either "Application" or "Automation" (for COM API)

Comment: @Pete: Looks like "Application" seems to be the norm. Though "Abstract" actually conveys more information IMO.

Comment: i know what the API's are but wat are the API calls????

Comment: @prasad: obviously API calls are calls to an API.  There still isn't enough context here to make the question answerable.

Comment: I want to handle the API calls of JWinAPI. But there is not much of information about it. Of waht instance is The method GetWindowProcess which returns JWinProcess??

Comment: @prasad: That's a rather obscure project that probably very few people know; you could try asking on its forum: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwinapi/forums/forum/1004252

Comment: Ok!! But still thank you for suggesting me..

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner for you using Java API probably will be importing some packages using 'import' and then creating objects and using their methods.

Comment: i know what the API's are but wat are the API calls????